# Where can I find an updated version of "libvlc" that will work with vlcj 2.1.0?

Tags: java, macos, runtimeexception, libvlc, vlcj

I am trying to compile code for the Java binding of VLC player with vlcj 2.1.0 and I am getting the error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: This version of vlcj requires version 2.0.0 or later of libvlc, found too old version 1.1.9 The Luggage.

The only version I can find for MacOS is "libvlc-1.1.9-macosx"

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had the same problem whilst doing this tutorial on using the bindings: http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/vlcj/tutorial2.php

My solution on OSX 10.6.8 was to just launch VLC and update to the 2.0.3 version. Now I'm running version 2.0.3 and pointing to /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/ and the bindings work. Note that updating to the latest version doesn't work as it introduces a separate issue: [VLCJ not working on Mac - plugin libvlccore.5.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341080/vlcj-not-working-on-mac-plugin-libvlccore-5-dylib).